# Visual studio randomly excludes source files from source control

Tags: tfs

I'm new with source control but since we are more than one developer in our company I started introducing git with Visual Studio 2013 Express and the Team Foundation Server. Now when I create a new project and add it to source control it seems that sometimes one random cs source file in the project is excluded from version control. In the Solution Explorer there is no check-in icon infront of the file. Also there is no other icon infront of it and if i publish the repository to the server the file isn't there.

I have no idea why the file is excluded and how to include it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is primary for programming Problems and not so much a Software Support. I think you are getting better help with asking directly in the MSDN

Comment: Thank you! OK I'll try it there. Thanks for the hint.